# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppService

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm

I've tried to inject Staff entity into app service, but it gives an error (written below). I don't know where the error can be - everything imported, typeorm can connect to database, migration runs

Error:

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Code:

*app.module.ts*

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { StaffEntity } from "./entities/staff.entity";

@Module({
  imports: [
      ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
          rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'client'),
      }),
      TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: "mysql",
          host: "localhost",
          port: 3306,
          username: "root",
          password: "",
          database: "test",
          entities: [StaffEntity],
          synchronize: false,
          autoLoadEntities: true
      }),
      TypeOrmModule.forFeature([StaffEntity])
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { StaffEntity } from "./entities/staff.entity";
import { Repository } from "typeorm";
import { LoginInterface } from "./types/login.interface";
const crypto = require('crypto')

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(StaffEntity) private staffRepository: Repository<StaffEntity>,
    ) {}

    verifyStuff(data: LoginInterface) {
        // some code
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to use [a custom repository](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-repository) instead

Comment: Looks like it might be an issue due to a circular reference, That's usually the case when I see `dependency` as a dependency token name